# Scaling bone multiplies texture

Tags: texturing, armature, bones, shaders

I followed this tutorial:
https://youtu.be/kB9cJ3wOoPk?t=1039

When I try to scale the bone to make the eye smaller the texture multiplies as shown here:

[image: 1st Image]

[image: 2nd Image]

Comment: your mesh: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/A8nlzxEe/ there's a UVWarp on the eye mesh, I don't know how you can avoid the image to be repeated, I don't know enough

Comment: It's all good my guy

Comment: you could simply rework your image so that you have a large margin of white, it would be another way around, not sure you can fix your problem otherwise  ;)

Comment: I would just add regular UV map to the eye mesh for eye rest pose. Then create en empty object controller to it. Add UVTransform modifier with an empty controlling it. Animate empty to scale/move the eye.

Comment: @moonboots You legend thanks to your idea I got it working! :) The other one from D. Skarn was a bit too confusing for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eye mesh has a *UVWarp* modifier. I don't know how to fix your problem with the current image, but another way around is to rework this image so that you have enough margin of white.

Comment: It didn't work, the first picture is the bottom two extended and the 2nd one is all extended https://imgur.com/a/xDw42sO

Comment: please share your file (only the eyes, make sure that you've packed its image): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=A8nlzxEe" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/A8nlzxEe/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize you said just eyes.